# Centering an image and placing a video inside the image

Tags: html, css

I am trying to center this image of TV but it keeps cutting off the right hand side and placing it to the left of the page.

I am also trying to place the black video screen inside the TV as if you are watching it on the TV.

Any ideas?

```
<div id="tv_container">
    <video>
       <source src="video/video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    </video>
 </div>

#tv_container {
    background: url('70 TV.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    width: 1080px; /* Adjust TV image width */
    height: 608px; /* Adjust TV image height */
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to do it like this:

```
#tv_container {
    background-image: url('70 TV.png');
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat; // this will fix cutting issue if I understood you well
    width: 1080px;
    height: 608px;
}
// center video horizontally and vertically
video {
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

And avoid using space in file names, name your image `70_TV.png` for example.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me so quickly!! The First thing worked but the video ended up in the middle of my header. Thanks for your help

Comment: I don't know how your header code looks like. Can you share full code with html and css of it?

Answer (score 0):

use `background-size:contain` so you `background` fits your `div`